# What is right hand side limit of Dirichlet eta function of -1?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

What is right hand side limit of Dirichlet eta function of -1 ?
Left hand side ia 1/4, right hand side doesn't exist as I understand, motivation : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF#Zeta_function_regularization

Comment: Why do you think one of the sides of the limit equation doesn't exist?

Comment: because left hand side limit of -1 is used for showing that 1 + 2 + 3 + ... = - 1 / 12 and I'm guessing that here hides the trick as 1 + 2 + 3 + ... has no limit

Comment: You seem to be referring to the old hoax that $\;1+2+\ldots=-\frac1{12}\;$ , but that is not what I see in the link you provide. Can you see that article talks of *regularized* sum $\;1+2+...\;$ ?

Comment: I've thought that this regularization is the source of hoax and that taking left hand side limit of Eta of -1 in absence of limit of -1 is the source of paradox, now it seems I don't understand what zeta regularization is ...